# In Azure ADF trying to copy data from ADLS to SQLDB, however, few of the JSON array data at the sink side is missing

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from ADLS to SQL-DB, however in source I have JSON file [refer link for JSON file that need to be copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4HHM.png)
However after debugging successfully, the data is not fully copied [refer link for the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVuI9.png) - please guide

I tried to copy JSON array data using copy activity from ADLS to SQL-DB, and was expecting to get complete data copied into SQL-DB from ADLS

Comment: If size of Data read and data written are not same, this does not mean data is not fully copied. Check the source data and sink data and check if any data is missing in the sink data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasize variation while copying data is acceptable since data gets compressed according to source and sink dataset type. If there is really data truncation happening at the sink side, it might be because of the length limitations for a nvarchar() field i.e. 4000 characters. Check :[nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#nvarchar---n--max--)